# How to force "A system restart is needed to complete the update process" message in KDE Plasma to be displayed?

Tags: kde, plasma

"A system restart is needed to complete the update process" notification is shown once after update of the package (which requires a reboot) is done. But it can be closed by an incident and user may forget to reboot the system really.

How do I force to show this message again in some time, similarly to how it's done in macOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the "A system restart is needed to complete the update process" notification you should update the timestamp of `/var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp` file:

```
sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp
```

Notification will be shown only if `/var/run/reboot-required` file exists.

You can run it periodically (e.g. once a day) to ensure it's shown to a desktop user so they do not forget to reboot the system.